# integer input check in C

Tags: c, input

I would like to ask you what's the most efficient way for checking user's input in C. I want the user to enter a 4 digit integer. How can I make sure that the user has entered exactly 4 digits and no letters?

Comment: for(int i=0;i<4;++i)if(!isdigit(in[i])) panic(); if(in[4]) panic(); ;-)

Comment: I thought to subtract the number 999 from the integer, because if the user has added a letter in the input C will neglect it and will save a three digit integer. then I check if the output it's positive or negative

Comment: Get input from the user as a string.  Loop over the string and check that each character is an integer using `isdigit` from `<ctype.h>`

Comment: Can the integer value start with leading zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

1) read as `string` or `char*`

2) check each char falls within 49-58 ASCII range.

Finally, convert into `int` using `atoi()` (or atol() in case of long) if there are only four chars in the string and satisfy (2)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker a string. A data format as defined in the C Standard in 7.1.1p1 (C99)

Comment: Don't check for the range 49-58; use `'0'` - `'9'`, or better yet call `isdigit((unsigned char)s[i])`.

Comment: Well, `char *` in C is called of string too

Comment: @ouah, "a string" or `string'? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

All input are taken as strings(console). what you can do is check if lengh is less than four, if so loop through and use `isdigit()` for each char to see if is digit.

For checking numeric you can do something like like:

```
 int isnumeric(char *str)
 {
     while(*str)
     {
        if(!isdigit(*str))
            return 0;
            str++;
     }
     return 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtol` function to convert your string to a `long`. `strtol` can do error checking to check you really got a  `long`. Then check the number is between `1000` and `9999` (for positive 4-digits decimal integers).